# Anyone have experience using the Nessi Python Network Simulator?

Tags: python, numpy

I am working on creating a simulation for the selective-reject ARQ protocol for my networking class. I found a great network simulator, written in python called Nessi:
http://jer.iict.ch/logiciels

The one problem is that it seems Nessi relies on an older version of python (2.4) than what I currently have installed on my computer(2.7).

There is almost no documentation and I am trying to figure out where to begin!

I have two questions:

1. Has anyone tried installing Nessi on Snow Leopard, OSX?
2. I am thinking of using virtualenv to have a contained version of
   python and the necessary modules for Nessi. Is there something else
   I should be considering?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run it in Snow Leopard.

Use a package management system like fink to install the dependencies required for this package, I think most of the dependencies can be installed using fink like(psyco, numpy, matplotlib,wxpython), you have to experiment with newer version of python to see how it goes, because certain libraries available in fink are for newer version of python.

Fink separates the binary it installs from system binaries, so you can work without fear of damaging your system binaries.